# Mutliple Node app with Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, url-rewriting

I'd like to run multiple node app throught a Nginx server for the reverse proxy. I actually have something like that in my config file :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name http://my.server.url;

    location / {
        root /absolute/path/to/index/;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /foo/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000; # here is an nodejs app runing
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

The problem : In my nodejs app, I receive url with the '/foo/' before.
I try to monkey arround with rewrite but honestly I'm confuse, so I'd like to get '/bar/' instead of '/foo/bar/', how should i proceed?

Comment: You don't have multiple node app here... For your problem I think you can do this : `proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:3000/foo/ /`
What is the first location ?

Comment: I didnt drop my full config file, but i have another location instruction for a second app. The first is just a index html page.  What i'd like to have is when i go to my server url ( www.myserver.example/foo/ ), my nodejs app in see "/" instead of "/foo/"

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand why you want have `/bar/` instead of `/foo/bar/`. You already have the first location with `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is called [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) in nginx

```
location /foo/ {
    rewrite  ^/foo(.*)$ /$1 last;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000; # here is an nodejs app runing
}
```